# Recommendations Service randomly throws IOExceptions

Tags: android, android-tv

I've added a Recommandation Service to my TV app, closely following the docs from here https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-row.html#service

The only part I left out is exception handling, and my service now reports a lot of IOExceptions. I know how to handle this errors but ...

Why is the service throwing an error in the first place, the TV is always connected to the internet?

Comment: the way to handle the exception depends on the exception details. YOu didn't post neither your code nor exception stacktrace.

Comment: I know how to handle the exception what I don't understand is why the service is throwing the error in the first place, the TV is always connected to the internet.

Comment: `YOu didn't post neither your code nor exception stacktrace.` Good luck fixing it on your own.

Comment: Haven't experienced but to think that there is no ideal signal thrown by any network or simply because you have unstable connection in the network. Let see for example [this code from the documentation in the section of "Using HttpsUrlConnection to Fetch Data"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html), it says that it will throw IOExeption if the connection to network is not successful. I think that's the reason, just an opinion.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 that sounds like a good explanation, but I was interested when this happens, do tv's have some sort of a power save mode in witch they cut internet connection maybe?